# phpMyAdmin primary key indicator showing grey on text

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin it's really hard to see which column has been assigned PK. If base on the color of icon, it's doesn't make sense because I assume column with data type text have a grey icon.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1OBNURD.jpg]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PhpMyadmin primary key identify by underline in column name.

In your case, you have underline in task_id.

other grey color means , you can't assign primary key to that column .

Comment: how about dotted underline?

Comment: This answer seems to be correct but is there any documentation proving that? I am not able to find any. And what about the dotted underline?